# How to count quantity with distinct?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have 2 templates, one representing a product sheet and the other one an actual product in stock.
The stock can have several products that have the same product sheet.
Example:
I can have a product record "Water bottle", and several "water bottle" in the stock.

My models:

```py
class Stock(models.Model):

    machine = models.ForeignKey(
        "machine.Machine",
        verbose_name=_("machine"),
        related_name="machine_stock",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        "client.Product",
        verbose_name=_("product"),
        related_name="product_stock",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    epc = models.CharField(_("EPC"), max_length=80)
    dlc = models.DateField(_("DLC"))

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)
    [...]
```

I want to retrieve the products in stock sorted by both DLC and name.
On my frontend I want to display a table with for each row:

- the name of the product
- the dlc
- the number of products with this name and this dlc

Example:

If I have 2 product sheets (Product Model) :

- water bottle
- bottle of coca cola

and I have 5 products in stock (Stock Model) :

- 2 bottles of water whose dlc is 02/04/2022
- 2 bottles of cola whose dlc is the 02/04/2022
- 1 bottle of cola whose dlc is 03/04/2022

I want to display 3 lines in my table:

Quantity | Name | DLC

2 | water | 02/04/2022

2 | cola | 02/04/2022

1 | cola | 03/04/2022

I tried with

```py
queryset = (
            Stock.objects.all()
            .select_related('product')
            .select_related('machine')
            .annotate(quantity=Count("product__name", distinct=True))
            .distinct("dlc", "product__name",)
            .order_by("-dlc")
        )
```

But django ORM don't accept annotate and distinct in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

It's works with:

```py
queryset = (
            Stock.objects.all()
            .select_related('product')
            .select_related('machine')
            #.annotate(quantity=Count("product__name", distinct=True))
            .distinct("dlc", "product__name",)
            .order_by("-dlc")
        )
            
        for result in queryset:
            result.quantity = Stock.objects.filter(dlc=result.dlc, product__name=result.product.name).count()
```

But I'm not sure that is the best method to use.